# Angular 5 use nutrionix app

Tags: angular

I tried to use Angular 5 to get nutrition data from nutritionix API.

But always get an error message 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients", ok: false, …}
error
:
{message: "child "query" fails because ["query" is required]", id: "b38aa437-1344-4512-a667-e8eb54564a69"}

Here is my code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOption = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
    'Content-Type': 'applicaiton/json',
    'x-app-id':'xxxxxxxxx',
    'x-app-key':'xxxxxxxxxx'
  })
}
@Injectable()
export class RecipeInfoService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

getNutritionInfo(ingrident:string):Observable<any>{
    let url = 'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients';

    let body=JSON.stringify({
      'query':"for breakfast i ate 2 eggs, bacon, and french toast",
      'timezone': "US/Eastern"
    })


    return this.http.post<any>(url,body, httpOption);

  }

}
```

Comment: No matter body is JSON stringify or not, get same error, and similar setting does work in postman

Comment: Typo. application spelling is wrong in ` 'Content-Type': 'applicaiton/json'`. It could be because of that

Comment: Anand, thank you very much!!! yes, this stupid mistake created this error